# Understanding Recursion, c++

Tags: c++, recursion, factorial

For the code below, could anyone please tell me why the function always returns "0" if the return value for the base case (n==0) is 0? I know in order to correct this function, I'd simply have to replace "return 0" with "return 1", however, I'm trying to understand why does it return 0 for the base case below.

Thanks for your help

```
int factorial(int n) { 
    if (n == 0) { 
        return 0; 
    } else {
        return n * factorial(n-1);
    }
}
```

Edit: Hopefully, the code below has no logical errors ...

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;

long double factorial (long double n) {
    if (n==0) return 1;
    if (n<0) return -fabs((n*factorial(n+1)));
    return n*(factorial(n-1));
}

int main () {
    long double n;
    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Factorial of " << n << " is " << factorial(n) <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're pasting some random code and ask "why is this code what it is"? What sort of answer do you expect for that?

Comment: `I know in order to correct this function, I'd simply have to replace "return 0" with "return 1"` Your question is "why is this code wrong?"? It returns 0 for the base case because it doesn't understand the definition of 0!, I suppose

Comment: @KerrekSB
Well, the sort of answers ppl have given below. Good luck commenting next time!

Answer (score 5):

If you take a look at how the factorial is defined you'll find something like:

```
f(0) = 1
f(1) = 1
f(n) = f(n-1) * n
```

So your function does indeed return the wrong value for `factorial(0)`. The recursion in this function basically works by decrementing `n` in every new function call of `factorial`.

Let's assume you call `factorial(3)`. `n` would that with 3, the else branch will get executed as `n` does not equal zero. We follow the third rule of our definition an call `factorial(2)` (which is n-1) and multiply the result of it by n. Your function will step down until `factorial(0)` is called and returns 0 which then is a factor of all previous calculations, resulting in `3*2*1*0`, and that equals to `0`.

Answer (score 5):

This code is simply wrong. No matter which n > 0 it gets as argument, every value is eventually multiplied with 0 and therefore factorial( n ) = 0 for all n > 0.

Comment: And for n < 0 it recurs infinitely and then overflows the stack.

Comment: @NickLH Well, you knew what I meant, right? :) I was assuming that factorial(n) should calculate the factorial of n...

Comment: @JoshuaClark hence the stackOverflow

Comment: @Sh4pe: The thing is, for any given piece of code, you can always imagine some other, *different* piece of code that does something else, correctly. As long as the OP isn't willing to describe her expectations, goals and problems, the question *has* no answer.

Answer (score 5):

It returns zero since any number times zero is zero. You start with some number n, say n=5. As you go through the recursion you have:

```
n * factorial(n-1)
5 * factorial(5-1)
5 * 4 * factorial(4-1)
5 * 4 * 3 * factorial(3-1)
5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * factorial(2-1)
5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 * factorial(1-1)
```

But factorial(1-1) is factorial(0) which returns 0, so you get :

```
5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 * 0 = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

> For the code below, could anyone please tell me why the function returns "0" if the return value for the base case (n==0) is 0?

Someone chose to do that. You'd have to ask the author why they did that.

> I know in order to correct this function, I'd simply have to replace "return 0" with "return 1", however, I'm trying to understand why does it return 0 for the base case below.

Likely because the person who wrote it thought 0! was equal to 0.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get you question entirely but lets cal the function f(int n): int okey to make it shorter

for n = 0 it will return 0 becaulse thats what you told it to do right: if(n == 0) return 0;
for n + 1 youll get the folowing pattern:
f(n+1) ==> n * f(n)  becaulse thats wat you told it to do otherwise right? and f again will evaluate.

so thats why youre function will return 0 in any case and if you alter the base case to 1 youll get:

Answer (score 0):

For whatever `n` (bigger than or equal to 0), you multiply a lot of numbers down to `factorial(0)` which returns 0.

The result of

```
n*(n-1)*(n-2)*...*3*2*1*0
```

is a big fat **`0`**

P.S. Besides not computing properly, the code has a major flaw. If you give it a negative number, you make it cry.